Add bank account payment Info to the processing email
I'm using a snippet to auto update the status from "on-hold" to Processing.  But by doing so, the email that is sent out (processing) does not contain the BACS bank account information.
I simply want to replicate the information shown in the old-hold email, but in the processing email where BACS payment is used.
I have found a snippet here which works, but this does not include the bank account payment instruction text added in the Woo admin payment BACS page.
I would like to retrieve the instructions, and the description text too, that is entered into the woo settings page for bacs
looking at class-wc-gateway-bacs.php I can see
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts', $this->account_details, $order_id );
and also
$this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
        $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions' );

I tried (from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53660619/1319778)
$bacs_accounts_info = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts');
    
    echo $bacs_accounts_info;

But that only returns the bank payment information. So how would I include the instruction text also in the below? (taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163433/1319778)
// this part is all good.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bacs_process_payment_order_status','filter_process_payment_order_status_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_process_payment_order_status_callback( $status, $order ) {
    return 'processing';
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163433/1319778
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {    

    echo '<p>Please make payment .... but how to show the instruction text etc backend admin (account_details)  </p>';
    
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin && 'bacs' === $order->payment_method && $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
    $gw = new WC_Gateway_BACS();

    $reflector = new ReflectionObject($gw);
    $method = $reflector->getMethod('bank_details');
    $method->setAccessible(true);

    $result = $method->invoke($gw, $order->id);
  }
          
}

edit: clarifying that I already know how to get the account information, I am asking for help in how to retrieve the Bank Instructions html text.
It appears to have a different object filter and I'm not seeing how to easily fetch it as part of the same gateway.
        // Define user set variables.
        $this->title        = $this->get_option( 'title' );
        $this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
        $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions' );



You will not get anything from get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts') if you echo it as it's an array. You need to use print_r( get_option('woocommerce_bacs_accounts') ); or var_dump( get_option('woocommerce_bacs_accounts') );…

I am using standard woo not blocks.

So, you can use $bacs_accounts = get_option( 'woocommerce_bacs_accounts'); that will give you an array of the registered banks accounts like in this answer working answer (still working with last WooCommerce version)

Yes, I got that now, but how to also return the instructions and description, like you have here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435964/1319778

I updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435964/3730754 answer code (see at the end).

Thank you for your help @LoicTheAztec however I see a fatal error when using your code from the linked answer.  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Gateway_BACS:: get_description()
